# Getting all lines into an array

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have an app script that executes when the a google form response is submitted. The app script is attached to the response google sheet.

I want to send out a an email by formatting the responses but since google form does not allow formatting of answers I have to do it in the app script.

The user will enter the response for a question in multiple lines. I want to take that response and create and unordered list for that questions.

For example: the user will enter the following response
this is a test
this should be another list item.
another one.

I want to format this as

- this is a test
- this should be another list item.
- another one.

to do this I have to get the response from the google sheet cell and split by new line (\n). For some reason I am unable to do so.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var values = e.namedValues;
  var htmlBody = '';
  for (Key in values) {
    
    Logger.log(Key + ' : '+ values[Key]);

    try {
      Logger.log(JSON.stringify(values[Key]));
    } catch(error) {
      Logger.log(error);
    }

    
        htmlBody += createSection(Key, values[Key]);
    
  GmailApp.sendEmail('abc@org.com', 'sending email', '', {htmlBody:htmlBody});
}

function createSection(sectionName, values) {
 
  Logger.log(sectionName + ' : '+ values + ' Length: ' + values.length);
  var linesHtml = createBulletList(values);
  var sectionHtml = '<h1>' + sectionName + '</h1>' + '<p><br></p>';
  sectionHtml += '<ul>' + linesHtml + '</ul>' + '<p><br></p>';
  return sectionHtml;
}

function createBulletList(values) {
  
  var listHtml = '';
  Logger.log('createBulletList ' + values + ' Length: ' + values.length);
  //listHtml += values.forEach(listItem);
  listHtml += listItem(values);
  Logger.log(listHtml);
  return listHtml;
}
```

I have tried split but for some reason it does not work on values[Key] object. I have tried JSON.stringify to flatten the object but the split('\n') still does not work on the string.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

using an explicit variable and using that instead of values[Key] fixed the issue

```
var cellValue = values[Key].toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you are trying to do:

```
function createBulletList(multiLineText) {  
  return (multiLineText + "")
    .split("\n")
    .map(line => "<li>" + line + "</li>")
    .join("\n");
}
```

Notes:

- The +"" part converts the value to text, in case it is a number or Date.
- split creates an array of texts
- map creates another array of html <li>
- join puts them back into a multi-line text (can be join("") if you don't want that)

Answer (score 0):

#### Sending unordered list

```
function onMySubmit(e) {
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  let itemA = e.values.map((v,i) => {if(i > 0) {return v}}).filter(e => e);
  let hl = "<ul>" + itemA.map(itm => `<li>${itm}</li>`).join("")  + "</ul>";
  //Logger.log(hl);
  GmailApp.sendEmail("recipient email","list",null,{htmlBody:hl});
}
```

Using values from onFormSubmit event object.

[image]

Using short answer questions